# Android - Activity Recognition lack of accuracy

Tags: android, activity-recognition

I'm testing the Android ActivityRecognition API and I used this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-recognize-user-activity-with-activity-recognition--cms-25851).

In order to get more accuracy I'm checking the confidence, the common limit I saw is that the confidence must be >= 75.

My application is running on the background and the activity recognition is updated for some interval of time.

But I've noticed some errors:

1. When the application is on background and I'm using another application like whatsapp or facebook messenger It detects "IN_VEHICLE"
2. When I'm actually driving it takes something like 10 minutes to detect I'm driving (I made it to notify the current activity me using Text to speech).

I tried to change the interval parameter value of `requestActivityUpdates` 
but it didn't improve the accuracy..

Any suggestion on how to improve the accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. 
So for anyone who encountered this problem..

I had an activity recognition using a background service so when 
the application is on bacgkround it should detect the user activity such : WALK, ON_VEHIClE and etc. 
But I noticed that when I launched another application and was typing a message, 
the movements of the device were translated into "ON_VEHICLE" by the activity recognition.

Comment: But this is not how it is supposed to work right? Were you able to improve the accuracy? 

I am currently doing feasibility study to decide if I should use native "Activity Recognition" or some 3rd party SDK.